# SimpleDateFormat returns incorrect date

Tags: java

I ran the below code and got ambiguous result:

```
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.ParseException;

    public class Test
    { 
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
             DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
             DateFormat secFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMYYYY"); 
             String date = "20171231";
             try {
                      Date newDate = format.parse(date);
                      System.out.println("Normal: "+newDate);          
                      System.out.println("Actual: 
                        "+secFormat.format(newDate));
                 } catch (ParseException ex) {
             System.out.println("Exception");
            }        
         }
       }
```

The above result I got is as below:
Normal: Sun Dec 31 00:00:00 UTC 2017
Actual: 31122018

31122018 is returned when the value is 31122017. Can anyone help me in getting the correct result as its a requirement in my project.

Comment: `YYYY` is not the same as `yyyy`. See [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4216745/5221149).

Comment: with ddMMyyyy also got 31122018 instead of 31122017 but when i tried with ddMMyyy I was able to get 31122017. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Here is a link to all the different formatting options for SDF.

Your issue is almost definitely in the yyyy/YYYY discrepancy.

Reference this link to be sure you have the format check right!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    SimpleDateFormat secFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy"); 
    String date = "20171231";
    try {
        Date newDate = format.parse(date);
        System.out.println("Normal: "+newDate);          
        System.out.println("Actual: " +secFormat.format(newDate));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception");
    }
```